# I am using Microsoft Visual studio windows forms, and i want to know that can I add buttons or get pictures

Tags: winforms, button, runtime, project

I am making my project in which I need help that, first I want to know that how I can manage between the files that is the header one, main and winform application, where do I have to add my oop code.
Secondly in my project I need to change the display image of my buttons at run time according to information I am providing to it, (if I say int n=1, then it should display the first picture but if I say n=2 it should display the second image). Note that I have found how to add multiple images, but changing it at the run time is not solving by me.
I would be highly grateful for the answers.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by header one and main? You can add code in any `.cs` file actually but you would add a Form to the project and right click that form and click _View Code_ which will take you to the code behind.

Comment: you need to show what you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a number of questions. You need to make sure you know C#, there are lots of book recommendations etc you will find on SO. Then learn about windows forms development.

I would recommend getting [Programming Windows Forms by Charles Petzold.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621535). A few things about the language may have changes but the windows forms framework hasn't changed much since 2005. You could also get [Visual C# 2010 Step by Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626707) for a more beginners overview on all features/options in .NET 4.

Here are some links:
[MSDN : Getting Started with Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229601.aspx)
[See this walkthrough for creating a simple calculator application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ew6tzdt.aspx)

There are some slightly advanced videos here you can watch later:
http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have learnt C language, and now I have to work on C++ as my object oriented course. I know I am asking too much, but the thing is that i am not much clear about winforms. Kindly answer me regarding c++

Comment: @Asjad Are you doing windows forms with C++ (or actually its C++ CLI) thats not really a beginners route. You need to read up more .net.